# How to get a JSON array without JSON_ARRAYAGG in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, json, array

I can't use a `JSON_ARRAYAGG` function introduced in MySQL 5.7.22 because I'm using MySQL 5.7.20. I would like to get a JSON array of a column values like I would get if I could use the function: `SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(column_name) FROM table_name;`

I got to this piece of SQL: `SELECT JSON_ARRAY(GROUP_CONCAT(column_name)) FROM table_name;` which  works almost like `JSON_ARRAYAGG`. The problem is when there is no rows it returns `[null]` instead of `null`.

What is the most efficient way of replacing a `JSON_ARRAYAGG` function with some equivalent? I would like to avoid something like this:

```
SELECT IF(
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name) FROM table_name) IS NOT NULL,
  (SELECT JSON_ARRAY(GROUP_CONCAT(column_name)) FROM table_name),
  NULL
);
```

Comment: is there a good cause, why you not simply update your database there should be not problem doing so.

Comment: Hi/Szia, and welcome to forum! As @nbk says, an in-place upgrade should be painless - it's only when changing major versions (i.e. 5.7 - 8.xx), that you have to backup/restore!

Comment: Besides JSON_ARRAYAGG returns [NULL] https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=44da8999516461b6495b8ae53525667a

Comment: Also, could you provide a fiddle (dbfiddle.uk) with your table structures and sample data?

Comment: I don't have a permission to do such upgrade. @nbk In your example a table is not empty. `JSON_ARRAYAGG` returns `null` if there are no rows in a table. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kSK45W5t3WEaMAWiAqrrCw/0

Answer (score 4):

Finally I've found a solution. I create a string array using `CONCAT` and `GROUP_CONCAT` functions and then cast it to `JSON`.

```
SELECT JSON_REPLACE(
    data,
    '$.numbers',
    IF(
      (
        SELECT COUNT(number) FROM numbers
        WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(data, CAST(numbers.id AS CHAR), '$.numbers') = 1
      ) > 0,
      (
        SELECT CAST(CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('"', number, '"')), ']') AS JSON) FROM numbers
        WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(data, CAST(numbers.id AS CHAR), '$.numbers') = 1
      ),
      NULL
    )
) AS json FROM foo;
```